# Python typing for a parameter can be None

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to create a tree structure with python typing annotation. The code is like this:

```
from typing import List

class TNode:
    def __init__(self, parent: 'TNode', data: str, children: List['TNode'] = []):
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.children = children


root = TNode(None, 'example')
```

But the code has a issue of type mismatching, Pycharm will raise `Expected type 'TNode', got 'None' instead`. Is there a way to solve this issue, or if there is a better way to design the class constructor?

Comment: There are many Python modules available that implement this feature.  I also don't recall type annotations to influence behaviour. However, from your code I ama assuming  the first Node is a parent node. Maybe you could replace the type annotations with `parent: ('TNode', None)`.

Comment: @NChauhan: implement *what* feature? This is about type hinting and how to use it correctly. Type hints are a standard Python library feature, no additional modules needed to install.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant the 'tree structure' has already been implemented

Comment: @NChauhan: right, but the vast majority of cases like these are asked by people using such a structure to learn the ropes of Python coding.  Using an external library instead would defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your parent node can be `None`, you need to mark the argument as `Optional` or explicitly use a `Union[None, 'TNode']` annotation:

```
from typing import List, Optional

class TNode:
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional['TNode'], data: str, children: List['TNode'] = []) -> None:
```

Side note: you probably do *not* want to use `[]` as a default value for children. Defaults are evaluated *once* and stored with the function object, so if you were to use the default value and mutate it, you mutate the shared default. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Set `children` to a default `None` sentinel value instead:

```
class TNode:
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent: Optional['TNode'],
        data: str,
        children: Optional[List['TNode']] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.children = children or []
```

The `children or []` expression will set `self.children` to an empty list whenever the `children` argument is a falsey value, including `None` and an empty list.

I also used a different formatting for the argument list, better suited for type-annotated arguments where the line length would exceed the recommended 80 characters line length limit.